# how the assembler manages "mov" instructions when source operand is a literal

Tags: assembly, x86

Lets say that in the source code i want a local variable to be assigned the number '3' so for example i type the instruction : movl $3, 8(%esp). I am not sure how it deals with such cases, because i have learned that in "mov" instructions in the "source operand" address should be specified and the content in that address is copied to the "destination operand". In case of a literal it is not an address because we want the number '3' to be copied and not the content in address number '3'. The only possible way i think of is that the assembler handles the string "$3" by convert it from ascii string to an integer and allocates an address for it and make it a const variable in the executable file. Does this actually what really happens ?

Comment: x86 **does have** `MOV` which can take an immediate source. No tricks needed. The immediate is embedded in the instruction. Consult an instruction set reference. You can also ask your assembler for a listing or use a disassembler. `movl $3, 8(%esp)` will become `c7 44 24 08 03 00 00 00`. You can see your constant is the last 4 bytes. The preceding `08` is the offset and the `44 24` are the modr/m and sib bytes encoding the `(%esp)`. `c7` is the opcode meaning `MOV r/m32, imm32`

Comment: Note that it can't be done the way you suggest (with the constant stored in memory), because x86 doesn't allow encoding two addresses in the instruction.

Comment: It's not the string `"$3"`, it's the integer `3`.  The `$` is AT&T syntax for an immediate, just like `mov $array, %edi` puts the address of the symbol `array` into a register.